# How to display similar JSON data in one table row

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, json

I want to display similar JSON data in one row.
I'm trying to compare `array index` with `keys index` and store in new `array`

**Expected result**

[image]

**this is my code**

```js
var array = [{ "english 1": "1", "english 2": "2", "hindi 1": "1", "hindi 2": "2", "gujarati 1": "1", "gujarati 2": "2", "marathi 1": "1", "marathi 2": "2" }]
keys = ['english', 'hindi', 'gujarati', 'marathi'],
grouped = {};

$.each(array, function (i, v) {
    $.each(keys,function (ii, vv) {
        var o = {};
        o[vv] = v[vv];
        grouped[vv] = grouped[vv] || [];
        grouped[vv].push(o);
    });
});
        
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(grouped, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableData" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Language</th>
                <th>col 1</th>
                <th>col 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="showData">

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have two column where you need to put value you can create separate `JSON Array` for both column where key will be same . Then, inside your each loop compare if the `key` matches with `keys` and only put value if match . Finally , to generate table you can append htmls in some variable using `+=` and append same to your tbody.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//suppose your json look like below :
var array = [{
  english: "1",
  hindi: "1",
  gujarati: "1",
  marathi: "1"
}, {
  hindi: "2",
  gujarati: "2",
  marathi: "2",
  english: "2"
}]

keys = ['english', 'hindi', 'gujarati', 'marathi'],
  grouped = [];

$.each(keys, function(i, v) {
  var o = {}; //create  obj
  o[v] = new Array() //create array with particular key
  $.each(array, function(ii, vv) {
    o[v].push(vv[v]) //push value only when key matches
  });
  grouped.push(o); //push array inside outer array
});
var htmls = "";
$.each(grouped, function(i) {
  $.each(grouped[i], function(key, val) {
    htmls += "<tr><td>" + key + "</td><td>" + val[0] + "</td><td>" + val[1] + "</td></tr>"; //generate htmls..
  });
});

$("#showData").html(htmls) //add same to tbody
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableData" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Language</th>
      <th>col 1</th>
      <th>col 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="showData">

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You should check out alpineJS. You can write an alpineJS template and just populate the data in an array and alpineJS would automatically populate the table.